# JsRender does not make the transformation for a for loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jsrender

The code works according to JsFiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/arame3333/PTWnq/6/

However in my MVC project it renders on the page as;

{{ for BusinessUnitName }} •{"BusinessUnitName":["Design and Build (Technical)","Architectual Design","ICT","Mechanical & Electrical ","Safety Management","Pre-Construction & Bid Preparation"]}
 {{/for }}

Why would this happen?

The relevant code is;

```
<ul id="departmentList"><%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AdditionalDepartmentList) %></ul>



<script id="DepartmentTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
            {{ for BusinessUnitName }}
                <li>{{:#data}}</li>
            {{/for }}
    </script>



function RefreshDepartments(o) {
        alert("Here are the results");
        var url = '<%: Url.Action("GetAdditionalDepartments", "DataService")%>';
        dataService.getAdditionalDepartments(
            o.EmployeeId,
            RenderDepartments,
            url
        );
    }

    RenderDepartments = function (data) {
        $('#departmentList').empty();
        $('#departmentList').html($('#DepartmentTemplate').render(data));
    };
```

The data comes from the controller here;

```
public ActionResult GetAdditionalDepartments(int employeeId)
        {
            var list = AdditionalDepartment.GetBusinessNamesByEmployeeId(employeeId);
            var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var json = jss.Serialize(new JsonArrayFormat(list.ToList()));
            return new JsonResult
                       {
                           Data = json,
                           JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                       };
        }
```

Edited markup - I cannot dispaly all of it;

```
    <form method="post" action="/Employee/Edit"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="IM9yFknHf1HKgZbd+UYsyMs9wQKL9dPK8zcRfi5uXTRQl7JvCq/Gr6cVq1wnUnao5Y2IToCDtEb5Vz/KnnxXSEDartM7fE9mQ7Cm7ynsFVE6ST2hhcygJX1ALAP67AXVlBBSf5ozczCctqb8ok+Blw==" type="hidden">

        <input id="Employee_EmployeeId" name="Employee.EmployeeId" value="258" type="hidden">
        <input id="Employee_ApproverEmployeeId" name="Employee.ApproverEmployeeId" value="340" type="hidden">
        <input id="CurrentCostRate_EmployeeId" name="CurrentCostRate.EmployeeId" value="258" type="hidden">
        <input id="CurrentCostRate_CostRateId" name="CurrentCostRate.CostRateId" value="303" type="hidden">
        <input id="Employee_UserName" name="Employee.UserName" value="aaronchampion" type="hidden">
        <input id="Employee_BusinessUnit_BusinessUnitName" name="Employee.BusinessUnit.BusinessUnitName" value="Construction" type="hidden">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Edit Employee</legend>

            <table id="editTable" class="groupBorder">


                      <tr>
                          <td style="text-align: right;">Additional Departments</td>
                          <td colSpan="2">
                              <span style="display: inline-block;">

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#DialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment").dialog({
                show: "fade",               
                width: 620,
                height: 850,
                title: 'Additional Departments/Divisions for Aaron Champion',
                modal: true,
                resizable: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                close: function () { $("#DialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment").html(""); },
                buttons: {
                    "": function () { $(this).dialog('close'); }, 
                    "Close": function () { $("#DialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment form").submit(); } 
                }
            }); 
        });

        var lockpopupDialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment = null;
        function callDialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment(employeeId) { 
            if(lockpopupDialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment != null) return;
            lockpopupDialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment = true;
            $.get('/AdditionalDepartment/AdditionalDepartments',
             { employeeId : employeeId }, 
            updateDialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment
            );
        }

        function OnSuccessDialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment(result) {
            if (result == 'ok') {
                $("#DialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment").dialog('close');

            }            

            else
            if(typeof(result) == 'object'){
            $("#DialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment").dialog('close');
             RefreshDepartments(result);
            }

            else {
                updateDialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment(result);
            }
        }        

        function updateDialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment(data) {
            lockpopupDialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment = null;
            $("#DialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment").html(data);
            $("#DialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment form").ajaxForm({


                beforeSubmit: function () { return $("#DialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment form").validate().valid(); },

                success: OnSuccessDialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment
            }); //ajaxForm
            $("#DialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment").dialog('open');
            $("#DialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment form input:visible:first").focus();
        }
</script>


                                <a href="javascript:callDialogAdditionalDepartmentsAdditionalDepartment(258)">Add/Edit additional departments/divisions</a></span>
                              <ul id="departmentList">

<li>Architectual Design</li>

<li>ICT</li>

<li>Mechanical &amp; Electrical </li>

<li>Safety Management</li>

<li>Estimating</li>

<li>HR and Training Development</li></ul>
                          </td>
                      </tr>


            </tbody></table>
        </fieldset>

    </form>

    <div>
        <a href="/Employee/List">Back to List</a>
    </div>

    <script id="DepartmentTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        {{ for BusinessUnitName }}
            <li>{{:#data}}</li>
        {{/for }}
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function RefreshDepartments(o) {
            alert("Here are the results");
            var url = '/DataService/GetAdditionalDepartments';
            dataService.getAdditionalDepartments(
                o.EmployeeId,
                RenderDepartments,
                url
            );
        }

        RenderDepartments = function (data) {
            $('#departmentList').empty();
            var data1 = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#departmentList').html($('#DepartmentTemplate').render(data1));
        };


    </script>



        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script id="DepartmentTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{ for BusinessUnitName }}
         <li>{{:#data}}</li>
    {{/for }}
</script>
```

The problem was in 3 whitespaces, it was hard to find problem, because **jsfiddle.net** example works fine. After all attempts to detect problem I asked **arame3333** for htmp-markup, then I just try it and found, that problem in template, correct one:

```
<script id="DepartmentTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{for BusinessUnitName}}
         <li>{{:#data}}</li>
    {{/for}}
</script>
```

Comment: I have put in the extra information you requested in the question.

Comment: @arame3333 It is hard to understand problem, without debugging, use two breakpoints (put one in action `return new JsonResult`) and other in javascript `RenderDepartments ` and compare results.

Comment: The data looks like this is from the breakpoint you suggest; "{\"BusinessUnitName\":[\"Design and Build (Technical)\",\"Architectual Design\",\"ICT\",\"Mechanical & Electrical \",\"Quality Management\"]}"

Comment: @arame3333 Try [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) and also check javascript function (I use firebug).

Comment: @arame3333 Sorry, for confusion, I remove it (I taking about update). Here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PTWnq/7/

Comment: Before parseJson, data looks like; data "{\"BusinessUnitName\":[\"Design and Build (Technical)\",\"Architectual Design\",\"ICT\",\"Mechanical & Electrical \",\"Safety Management\"]}" String. AFTER parseJson it looks like; BusinessUnitName [Design and Build (Technical),Architectual Design,ICT,Mechanical & Electrical ,Safety Management] Object, (Array). From doing that, the output renders as {{ for BusinessUnitName }} •[object Object]
 {{/for }}

Comment: @arame3333 please, put breakpoint on this line `$('#departmentList').empty();` and show screenshots of `data` param (with and without parseJson). It's something simple, but it hard to understand remote.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16867/discussion-between-webdeveloper-and-arame3333)

Comment: I would like to but my companies blocking policy does not allow this.

Comment: From chat: in console you see same object as in first jsfiddle example? if you replace data param in your function with data from console, what result you see? everything works fine?

Comment: Another message: I carefully checked your post second time, as I understand you receive array of objects? 'Object, (Array)' and after render we have object. You need {field:[]}, not [{field:[]}]. Please, show fiddler traffic (after ajax request click on request and save it in archive).

Comment: @arame3333 No, on JsFiddle is absolutely correct object, I think that your server return something wrong and we lose formatting here. I also can`t view your site by ip/domain? Compare two object after jsonParse, they can't be equal.

Comment: I deleted my last comment as I reread your advice. I copied the code from JsFiddle and used the data from there in my app. However I got the same invalid rendering as before.

Comment: @arame3333 I can't believe you) Now we knew, that it is not a server problem. If you put everything as in JsFiddle, it must work, maybe you use some old version of JsRender? Try to compare all.

Comment: After jsonParse, my data looks like BusinessUnitName [Architectual Design,ICT,Mechanical & Electrical ,Safety Management,Marketing,Estimating,HR and Training Development] Object, (Array)

Comment: @arame3333 Ok, it is hard to understand text visualization, but as I can see you receive array of objects. Try `render($.jsonParse(data)[0])`. It`s just for test, this is not solution.

Comment: Ok I tried that. I get {{ for BusinessUnitName }} •
 {{/for }}

Comment: When I try it without parsing, I get {{ for BusinessUnitName }} •{
 {{/for }}

Comment: @arame3333 could you send me rendered html-murkup?

Comment: put in the question. Had to edit it as it would not go in otherwise.

Comment: @arame3333 Good, because that's how it's supposed to be done. :-)

Comment: @arame3333 Job done ;) I remove 3 whitespaces from template in for loop. [jsfiddle.net/PTWnq/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/PTWnq/8/) Here is not working example: [jsfiddle.net/PTWnq/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/PTWnq/9/) (just compare them)

Comment: Genius! I have to admit you advised me to do that and I thought I did. Well that is one lesson I won't forget! Thank you!

Comment: @arame3333 Not at all, have a nice day )