# JsRender is not rendering as expected

Tags: jsrender

This is my template;

```
<script id="DepartmentTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        {{ for BusinessUnitName }}
            <li>{{:#data}}</li>
        {{/for }}
    </script>
```

This is where I send the data;

```
RenderDepartments = function (data) {
            $('#departmentList').empty();
            $('#departmentList').html($('#DepartmentTemplate').render($.parseJSON(data)));
        };
```

And this is where I put the data;

```
<ul id="departmentList"><%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AdditionalDepartmentList) %></ul>
```

This is the data received into the function data parameter;

```
{\"BusinessUnitName\":[\"Design and Build (Technical)\",\"Architectual Design\",\"ICT\",\"Mechanical & Electrical \",\"Safety Management\"]}
```

I do not know if I need to use the jquery $.parseJson, but either way the data does not render properly.
With $.parseJson it renders as;

```
{{ for BusinessUnitName }} 
•[object Object]
 {{/for }}
```

Without it renders as

```
{{ for BusinessUnitName }} 
•{"BusinessUnitName":["Architectual Design","ICT","Mechanical & Electrical ","Safety Management","Marketing"]}
 {{/for }}
```

So on the screen I am seeing some of the template definition, rather than a list.
How do I fix this?

Comment: We can continue yesterday discussion ;) In this question: [JsRender does not make the transformation for a for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491655/jsrender-does-not-make-the-transformation-for-a-for-loop/12491761#comment16809499_12491761) (look chat link)

Comment: Yes. I thought I would set it out again to make things clearer. it would be good to chat but as I mentioned my company policy does not allow it.

Comment: answer in previous question, I didn't understand that you taking about chat yesterday...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in whitespaces, after removing them, code works as expected:

```
<script id="DepartmentTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{for BusinessUnitName}}
         <li>{{:#data}}</li>
    {{/for}}
</script>
```